# issues with reading data from csv

Tags: c, csv, struct

I am working on a code in c that needs to read csv data and enter it into a structure.  Admittedly I both am more familiar with c++ and haven't done much with reading from files before so I could be missing something really obvious.  But when I check the structure array after it supposedly loaded the data, I get the right number of lines but all but the second one are blank- and that one for some reason just has a smiley face...

Here is my code:

```
void load_items(){
char file_name[20], buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
FILE *file;
int i;

printf("Enter the file to load data from: ");       //data.csv for here
scanf("%s", file_name);

file=fopen(file_name,"r");

if(file==NULL)
{
    printf("Can't open %s\n",file_name);
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else {
    printf("Congrats! you opened %s as your data source!\n", file_name);        //test to make sure opened file
    while((fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer),file)) !=NULL)          //while the line isn't blank
    {
        scanf(buffer,"%s,%s,%d,%d",&places[i].name,&places[i].category,&places[i].x,&places[i].y);      //enter data into proper place
        printf("|%-23s|%-20s\t| ( %d, %d) |\n",places[i].name, places[i].category, places[i].x,places[i].y);    //test to see data
        i++;
    }
}
fclose(file);
}
```

Here is what the info it is reading from looks like:

```
STARBUCKS COFFEE,cafeteria,7,11
Restaurant UNIVERSAL CLUB,cafeteria,18,16
PHONON CAFE ROOM,cafeteria,7,12
Craig's Cafe SEATTLE ESPRESS,cafeteria,18,11
Cafeteria NANAMI-TEI,cafeteria,11,7
IB Cafe,cafeteria,11,9
Restaurant Chez Jiroud,cafeteria,15,10
Labo Shop (NU CO-OP Shop),shop,29,19
NU CO-OP North,shop,11,5
Family Mart,shop,13,11
South Cafeteria,cafeteria,4,17
NU CO-OP South,shop,5,17
Amenity House,shop,6,17
FOREST Books & Cafe,cafeteria,19,7
Green Salon Higashiyama,cafeteria,21,8
Toyoda Auditorium / Symposion,Convention facility,17,15
Noyori Conference Hall,Convention facility,21,14
E & S Hall,Convention facility,16,9
Sakata & Hirata Hall,Convention facility,19,11
```

And here is what I am actually getting:

```
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|☺                      |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
|                       |                       | ( 0, 0) |
```

If it wasn't for that weird smiley I would think it just wasn't reading anything, or not transfering it into the struct right, but as it is I am baffeled.  Any advice would be very welcome, thank you for your time!

Comment: What is `places`? Is it an array? Of structures? What is the definition of the structures? Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Also, reading and parsing of a CSV file is ***deceptively*** simple. In reality it's much harder than it seems, which is why I always recommend people asking questions about parsing such files to try and find a library to handle it for them.

Comment: To debug, print out the lines you are reading with fgets() and verify that you are passing over the whole file. Then check the return from sscanf() (not scanf). The check you are reading the fields into temporaries correctly. Then check you are assigning the fields to your in-memory structure.

Comment: Uninitialised "i" ?

Comment: Your comment on `while((fgets(...)) !=NULL) //while the line isn't blank` is not true: a blank line will be read as a string consisting of a newline and a nul terminator. The `NULL` is returned when end of file has been reached.

Comment: The missing initialization of variable `i` already mentioned is a major problem. Another major problem is the use of `scanf`. You probably wanted to use `sscanf`

Comment: The formatting width of `23` is too small to tabulate `Toyoda Auditorium / Symposion` nicely.

Comment: While the uninitialized variable `i` is a big problem, I'm more worried about the structure members `name` and `category`. If they are *pointers* instead of arrays then that is a worse problems than `i` being uninitialized.

Comment: I didn't include the whole code since it is huge, but places is an array of structures- name and category are both arrays, and the x and y are ints.  Unfortunately using a library to parse the file is not allowed, so I am stuck trying to do it without.  Thanks for catching that 'i' though, originally it was being used in a for loop and I forgot to initialize it after I removed the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fscanf` to read from file instead of `scanf` and also use `%[^,]`(read all except ',') instead of `%s`.

Codesnip: `while(fscanf(file, "%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d", &places[i].name, &places[i].category, &places[i].x, &places[i].y) == 4)`

Comment: Thank you! that '%[^,]' instead of '%s' worked great.